# How to download com.azure.android:azure-communication-ui-calling:1.0.0 package from github and configure in the project

Tags: android, azure

I'm trying to download **com.azure.android:azure-communication-ui-calling:1.0.0** from GitHub and configure it locally to do a few UI changes.
I'm downloading the package from github link https://github.com/Azure/communication-ui-library-android/releases/tag/calling-v1.0.0 and extracting the files from it.

When I try to import the package by going **file->new->import module** in android I'm getting the error mentioned below

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'ui_library_version_name' for project ':azure-communication-ui' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import `com.azure.android:azure-communication-ui-calling:1.0.0` in android and follow the below steps:

- Make sure you have the required module `azure-communication-ui` in the directory you are looking for.
- Then, open your Android Studio project:

  1. Go to `File=>New=>Import Module`.

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/VbJkNJA.png)]

```
2. Navigate to the directory of the module which you want to import.
3.  Select the module directory and click the `Finish` button.
```

[image]

(or)

1. Add the below dependency to your app's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-ui-calling:1.0.0'
}
```

Check if you have defined variable `ui_library_version_name` in `build.gradle` with its value `1.0.0` .

```java
ext {
ui_library_version_name='1.0.0'
}
```

In such case you can define your dependency as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-communication-ui-calling:$ui_library_version_name'
}
```

**Synced project with ***Gradle*** files.**

- After adding the dependency, sync your project to make sure the changes are done properly:

  1. Click the `Sync Now` button that appears in the top-right corner of Android Studio (or) go to `File` and select `Sync Project with Gradle Files`.